# Setting Exact Length for producing a CV

Tags: formatting

I am currently working on my CV. I found a template online, and the code at the beginning is as follows:

```
 \documentclass[margin,line]{res}


\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in

% if using pdflatex:
%\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
%\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight} 

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}
```

I am, however, unable to decipher what part of the code lets me select the page length. I want to page length to be longer, so that I can ensure that my CV fits in one page (as of now, its 1 page and 1 line!). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to the preamble (just below `\documentclass[..]{res}`) to see the exact text block that will be used.

Comment: It shows me the text block: I do not, however, know how to  manipulate the specific dimension...

Comment: Well, all content you post should fit within that text block (top to bottom). If it doesn't, then you're doing something weird. If it does and you still want to change this block size, it's best to use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). For example, `\usepackage[margin=1in,left=2in]{geometry}`. Note that the [`res` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) puts the `\opening` into the left margin (hence my guess with `left=2in`). You may have to fiddle around with the respective margins.

Answer (score 1):

You have `\textwidth=6.0in`. Setting `\textheight=10in` (say) `\paperheight30cm` (say) changes the height of the text  (without spaces for headers and footers). The total height must be less than maximal TeX dimension, but that is about 5 meters.

In your case an alternative way is to set

```
`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.98} % some value slightly less than 1
```

if it is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I included the textheight command as well, but all it is doing is pushing the page number down without increasing the total permissible length of text on the document.

Comment: Should I include both text height and paper height?

Comment: I tried with both: it does not seem to work.

Comment: @ChinG No. Probably `\textheight` is enough. But you can try obtain a bit of space giving a fake height of paper. This depends on printer.

Comment: @ChinG And what abour changing `\baselinestretch`?

Comment: Both aren't working. \textheight is simple pushing the page number further below, without allowing me to increase the amount of text on the main section.

Comment: A Minimal Working Example (with fake data, but illustrating the problem) can help to fix the problem.  You have got some lists and their behaviour is unknown for us.